# How to reduce the load in the memory RAM

Tags: ram, swap

I have my Ubuntu 20.04 server with many cryptocurrencies daemons, I only have this kind of load in this server. Sometimes the server is running out of memory for these daemons, even if I have enough memory in swap partitions, this is an example:

[image]

I guess the server is running out the memory because the RAM is almost full, I would like to reduce the load in the memory RAM, changing something to the swap partition, is this possible? Or there is another best way to do something to help the server not run out of memory?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

`free -h` output:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           62Gi        60Gi       318Mi       0.0Ki       2.1Gi       1.7Gi
Swap:         381Gi       121Gi       260Gi
```

`sudo sysctl vm.swappiness` output:

`vm.swappiness = 70`

Comment: I run many cryptocurrencies daemon, this is the load of this server.

Comment: Show me `free -h` and `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I put the outputs in the question.

Comment: Either reduce the number of cryptocurrencies daemons, or force a maximum RAM size per daemon, or try vm.swappiness=80.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what utility this is a snapshot of, but analysing memory usage is tricky. For example, Linux will cache stuff in memory because... hey why not. So if I run:

```
find . -type f | xargs cat >/dev/null
```

When it's finished, you might find all the memory is "used" because it is caching your whole file system. However it isn't really used, because its caching stuff you'll never need again. So you tend to want to analyse not how much memory is used, but how hard your swap partition is getting hammered. If its not getting hit hard, then you may have plenty of memory. You could try disabling your swap. Does the server run fine without it? Maybe you have plenty of memory. I'd still enable swap though because it can get rid of rarely used things. As far as controlling swap, for the most part you can't control what's put there, the kernel does that for you. Which it generally does a good job of.

Comment: The RAM is used by many cryptocurrencies daemon, I only have this running on the server, but sometimes the daemons run out of memory.

Comment: Well, I'd say watch the IO on the swap partition. If it's low, then you're fine. If not, you need more actual RAM.

Comment: The screenshot is from htop